# SP Training Sites

Tags: training

I am a novice in SharePoint and need training.  Can someone recommend a complimentary self-training site?  I've been assigned to develop a team calendar in SharePoint.

Comment: If you search for free training tutorials on Google, you will get many. But here on SP.SE, questions related to specific SharePoint problems are asked and answered. Yours is a kind of opinion oriented, which will not have a definitive answer and might get closed.

Comment: Also be sure to check the Related bar on the right for more suggestions and similar topics.

Answer (score 2):

You can register a 30 days trial account with https://www.pluralsight.com.  There are many good courses that you can attend in 30 days trial. One particular course which might be useful is: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/sharepoint-2013-business-professionals.  If you just want to learn little bit about calendars here is the video on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfQFMOLbiO4.  I am sure there are many other resources available so please search YouTube also.

Hope this helps!